# How model 3-stage rocket to LEO in STK

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I'm trying to design a three-stage rocket ascent flight trajectory to LEO using AGI's Software SKT but I'm in trouble. Could anyone help me with designing it?

Comment: Could you explain your problem a more detailed?
What are your STK licenses. What do you know about the trajectory? How realistic do you want it to have?

Comment: Hi @Forbraer welcome to Stack Exchange! If you have a look around at other questions you'll see they are fairly specific and are written so that they can have a clear, concise and correct answer. This is definitely the right site to look for help, but *could anyone help me with designing it?* is way too broad. Like the other comment suggests, please add more information about your specific situation and chose one small part of the problem for each question you ask.

Comment: For example, have you had success with one and two stage rockets already and it's only the three stages that's the problem, or in fact are you really just getting started. If so, please explain what you have gotten working so far. Thanks, and *welcome to Space!*

Comment: Well, I'm new using STK. I don't to be so strict in simulation, just want to set some inputs as Isp, fuel mass, structure mass, things like we use in Tsiolkovisk's equation.

Comment: I recieved it in AGI Fórum: " 
this is not an easy task, especially getting the attitude right is tricky. Start out with an initial state segment. Set the coordinate system to Earth Fixed, set the coordinate type to Mixed Spherical and start stationary at the location you want to take off from. Then add a maneuver segment that initially sends you straight up so use a reference frame that has an up or down component. [...]

Comment: [...] Then add another maneuver segment that adds a slight roll, you probably want this in some Earth fixed system for now. Add another maneuver segment that switches over to an inertial velocity aligned system. Then add update segments at the appropriate times to account for the mass loss/drag changes during each stage separation "